# Do we need shuffle the entries before training gbdt by xgboost?

Tags: machine-learning, boosting

For example, the first 10 samples are taken from patient 1, the next 8 samples are taken from patient 2 and the next 12 samples are taken from patient 3 etc... Using the samples as trainset within its original order will make our gbdt classification model's performance weaker ? Should we shuffle it before training ?

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to shuffle training data - the model only cares about aggregate statistics of the data at each node, and these statistics are not sensitive to ordering.

However, it sounds like you have multiple observations from the same patients. If this is the case, we can suspect that the observations are **dependent** and this is not something that XGBoost is designed to model. Perhaps you would be better served  by using a model that can account for dependent data structures.

Comment: Is this absolutely right? For example, `XGBClassifier` has a parameter called `subsample` so you can take a fraction of the observations for each boosting tree. In this case, not shuffling the data may not give some quite different results? (I may be wrong; I am just asking because I like to learn)

Comment: Using subsample applies random sampling. Shuffling is redundant.

Comment: Cool! But this is because this specific implementation is done with random sampling so it is not only that the "the model only cares about aggregate statistics of the data at each node, and these statistics are not sensitive to ordering". I mean is that there are some points at Xgboost which in principle could oblige us to do shuffling if they were a bit different (e.g. without random sampling etc)

Comment: No, there aren't.